# Understanding cause of an AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am a beginner at discord.py and can't understand why my bot is not running.
I use VS Code IDE to code and execute my bot through the Command Prompt or Repl.it.
I was gonna make a bot chant some lines 24/7 in a discord server.

When I try to run my bot, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    msg = message.content
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

... and after lots of thinking and a little researching (I found no solution).. I tried adding from discord import message,
... aaandd.. error. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    msg = message.content
AttributeError: module 'discord.message' has no attribute 'content'
```

Can somebody please help me?
Here's my code (in testing phase):

```py
# bot.py
import discord
from discord import message
import os
import time

client = discord.Client()

msg = message.content
sendmsg = message.channel.send
ss = 'not chanting'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
  print('I am ready to chant.')

async def chant():
  await asyncio.time(1)
  print('test passed!')
  await sendmsg('passed the test')

async def on_message():
    if msg == '$chant help':
      print('The command \"$chant help\" was called')
      await sendmsg('$chant help - gives a list of commands I can do\n$start chanting - starts chanting in the specified channel\n$stop chanting - stops chanting')

    if ss == 'not chanting':
      if msg == '$start chanting':
        print('The command \"$start chanting\" was called')
        ss = 'chanting'
        await sendmsg('Ok. Chanting now.')
        await sendmsg('reference (this message triggers the code to chant)')

    if ss == 'chanting':
      if msg == '$stop chanting':
        print('The command \"$stop chanting\" was called')
        ss = 'not chanting'
        await sendmsg('Ok. Stopping chanting...')
        await sendmsg('Please wait...')
      
      elif message.user == '{client.user}':
        if msg.contains('reference'):
          chant()

    
client.run('no token 4 u')
```

Comment: where do i add channel id

Answer (score 0):

The discord module's message does not have any content. so here is fixed code.

```py
# bot.py
import discord
import os
import time

client = discord.Client()

ss = 'not chanting'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
  print('I am ready to chant.')

async def chant(message):
  await asyncio.time(1)
  print('test passed!')
  await message.channel.send('passed the test')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content  # Message content is passed on by the server and is not available through module.
    global ss
    if msg == '$chant help':
      print('The command \"$chant help\" was called')
      await message.channel.send('$chant help - gives a list of commands I can do\n$start chanting - starts chanting in the specified channel\n$stop chanting - stops chanting')
    
    if ss == 'not chanting':
      if msg == '$start chanting':
        print('The command \"$start chanting\" was called')
        ss = 'chanting'
        await message.channel.send('Ok. Chanting now.')
        await message.channel.send('reference (this message triggers the code to chant)')

    if ss == 'chanting':
      if msg == '$stop chanting':
        print('The command \"$stop chanting\" was called')
        ss = 'not chanting'
        await message.channel.send('Ok. Stopping chanting...')
        await message.channel.send('Please wait...')
      
      elif message.user == '{client.user}':
        if msg.contains('reference'):
          await chant(message)

    
client.run('no token 4 u')
```

Comment: still won't work, `sendmsg = message.channel.send` will raise an error since `message` isn't defined there

Comment: @Ceres It is defined. I have imported message from discord. Or maybe am i supposed to replace it with `from discord.message.channel import send as sendmsg`

Comment: it now has an error saying:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    sendmsg = message.channel.send
AttributeError: module 'discord.message' has no attribute 'channel'```

Comment: see, `message` is an instance of `discord.Message`, that means its an object, that has properties like channel, in your case, **all messages will point to the same channel**, but in reality there are multiple channels and even then your `message` doesn't actually point to a channel

Comment: I tried adding: from discord.message.channel import send as sendmsg
It threw me an error on the face:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from discord.message.channel import send as sendmsg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.message.channel'; 'discord.message' is not a package```

Comment: hmm then OP needs to specify channel id

Comment: @xcodz-dot, then it will keep sending messages to that channel and not the channel in which the message was sent.

Comment: @xcodz-dot can we try solving this in my dms?

Comment: pls wait, then i will just go and fix it

Comment: the solve is defining `sendmsg = message.channel.send` inside the `on_message` function...

Comment: @ceres ok i will try

Comment: pls try now I have made the fixes.

Comment: @Ceres defining sendmsg inside on_message might not help because chant also requires sendmsg function

Comment: and yes just edittied the answer, added client.event decorator to on_message. pls retest